# how to make loop for a cube going up and down in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

> This example code the box only moves up I want it move up and down

```
    BoxGeo = new HREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10)
    BoxMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: 0xf3e54f
    }),
    cab = new THREE.Mesh ( BoxGeo, BoxMat);
    scene.add(cab);
   
cab.position.y  += 1;
```

Comment: It only goes up because Math.random() will give you a value between `[0, 1]` so adding that to `.y` makes it go up.

Answer (score 0):

Since Math.random() gives you numbers in the `[0, 1]` range, you can change this range to  `[-1, 1]` with a simple equation:

```
let displacement = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2.0;
cab.position.y += displacement;
```

Comment: When the random number is negative, it'll move down. When the random number is positive, it'll move up. I'm not sure I understand what else you're looking for.

Comment: You never mentioned it couldn't go below zero. I suggest you make these things clear in your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

You need `Math.sin()` in your animation loop in order to move the object up and down smoothly.

```js
cab.position.y = Math.sin(elapsedTime) + 1
```